# Replacing a value for a given key in Kusto

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I am trying to use the `.set-or-replace` command to amend the "subject" entry below from sample/consumption/backups to sample/consumption/backup but I am not having much look in the world of Kusto.

I can't seem to reference the sub headings within Records, data.

```
    "source_": CustomEventRawRecords,
"Records": [
{
                "metadataVersion": "1",
                "dataVersion": "",
                "eventType": "consumptionRecorded",
                "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z",
                "subject": "sample/consumption/backups",
                "topic": "/subscriptions/1234567890id/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/webhook",
                "data": {
                        "resourceId": "/subscriptions/1234567890id/resourceGroups/RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm"
                        }, 
                        "id": "1234567890id"
}
],
```

Command I've tried to get to work;

```
.set-or-replace [async] CustomEventRawRecords [with (subject = sample/consumption/backup [, ...])] <| QueryOrCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're already manipulating the data, why not turn it into a columnar representation? that way you can easily make the corrections you want to make and also get the full richness of the tabular operators plus an intellisense experience that will help you formulate queries easily

here's an example query that will do that:

[execute query in browser](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5VSO2/CMBDe8yusTCABTvoGiamqUIcuqOrQqqqMfYBbHEe2E4La/vfazoMoREhNPNj3Pc6%20O0aM/Vc7QINihtghIYLT4Vu1GXyHWmaKwkc4Q%20F9po0UDzkkZkn2S6BSMR2OgrDeztBb8B2EAgxh1vUFlOYycdLY0ToxFwJn9nxIwQWoTHQmUmPx0hHYkcOF58TT22gcxXY9R9HMr0lUfq%20OrLPVJ1DjqJqIdAe45YpXhH5lqb%20zkSmnjoatRFPFPUPj%20OLy6vrm9m4acYYVlM9fKGllWG1wqmTOmX0EfuJUSS3XZuIrslCW70013sNqK%20VX/WabxVal9npk/8y6XPRmvZcizQzgnCuTkd0ToVuegMa5CIPfEQpC7hO1nS0QvP8O34MfBIWBhCFVdg7NUTGpumhBkY%20hSEmDz1UDVbqqzFZnpDaKJ5tByZlUyPDIbZH5ej1oTvPzLTqDWvA0TWfqeq7WYbS053X9mmZ0exQN1uL72Til%20nDnKtaxlfqIcdaTizOnthPi6jEme3JAqBjVna03f4C5r3roAwAA)

```
datatable (x: dynamic)[dynamic({"source_": "CustomEventRawRecords",
"Records": [
{
"metadataVersion": "1",
"dataVersion": "",
"eventType": "consumptionRecorded",
"eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z",
"subject": "sample/consumption/backups",
"topic": "/subscriptions/1234567890id/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/webhook",
"data": {
"resourceId": "/subscriptions/1234567890id/resourceGroups/RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm"
}, 
"id": "1234567890id"
}
]})]
| extend records = x.Records
| mv-expand record=records
| extend subject = tostring(record.subject)
| extend  subject = iff(subject == "sample/consumption/backups", "sample/consumption/backup", subject)
| extend metadataVersion = tostring(record.metadataVersion)
| extend dataVersion = tostring(record.dataVersion)
| extend eventType = tostring(record.eventType)
| extend topic= tostring(record.topic)
| extend data = record.data
| extend id = tostring(record.id)
| project-away  x, records, record
```